# Groovy XML and the "xml:" namespace

Tags: groovy, xml-serialization, xml-parsing

I'm writing a couple of scripts the modify xml files. The files in question use the xml:lang element. Groovy (XmlSlurper) seems to be inserting a tag0 namespace, which I wouldn't mind too much, except it seems to break later processing with XmlUtil.

An example:

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

String source = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
    <one xml:lang="en">First</one>
    <one xml:lang="de">Second</one>
</root>
"""

def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(source).declareNamespace(xml: "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")
println root
String xml = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind{ 
    mkp.xmlDeclaration() 
    out << root 
}
println xml
println XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

results in

```
[Fatal Error] :2:44: The value of the attribute "prefix="xmlns",localpart="tag0",rawname="xmlns:tag0"" is invalid. Prefixed namespace bindings may not be empty.
```

The xml: namespace is supposed to exist by default, and I've tried adding it with .declareNamespace() but it doesn't seem to help. I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but Google hasn't been able to tell me what it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found [this thread](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/XmlSlurper-StreamingMarkupBuilder-amp-Namespaces-td336787.html) from a few years ago, which says:

> The problem is that the original document uses the default namespace.
>
> SMB does not normally use the default namespace so it invents a tag and uses it to explicitly mark each element in the namespace. As far as an XML parser is concerned it doesn't matter how the namespace is indicated. However there are cosmetic reasons why it is sometimes desirable to use default namespaces.
>
> If you put `mkp.declareNamespace("":  "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee")` as the first line in your builder closure you should get the output you want.

**However, this doesn't seem to work**

The only solution I have found is to make the Slurper ignore namespaces and validation;

```
def root = new XmlSlurper(false,false).parseText(source)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not having that effect for me. I get the exact same error as before. I'm in groovy 1.8.6, how about you?

Comment: Just checked again, and you're right...  Sorry...  I'll remove this, and have another go at seeing if I can work it out...

Comment: @ErikAckerman Updated my answer to show the only solution I have found

Comment: Perfect! That works perfectly for me since the filter chain that this is part of will have already validated our input. Thanks!

Comment: @tim_yates: +1 .I have a similar [problem too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295178/xml-generation-gives-fatal-error-using-groovy), anyhow did you happen to get any other solution?

Comment: @AbhishekSimon Currently, I don't know of any other solution :-(

Comment: Can you try with the latest versions of Groovy (from github or one of the snapshot releases)? I just committed a fix for this issue which might fix your problem:

https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5879

And if not, it would be good to know before the next release, so further improvements can be made if needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Setting default namespace to empty tag works for me (no "tag0"added).
I use default XmlSlurper constructor to have working namespacing and validation, eg:

```
def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(source).declareNamespace(xml: "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")
```

When binding, declare empty namespace:

```
def writer = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
    mkp.declareNamespace("": "") //get rid of "tag0"
    mkp.declareNamespace(xml: "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace") 
    mkp.yield root
}
```